# Alone pawn: LaTeX

Tags: chess

If you know, how to work with chess in LaTeX, please help!

I want to make an alone pawn to go.

This code works, but shows lots of other pieces:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{chessboard, skak}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \newgame\setchessboard{markstyle=border,color=blue}
        \only<1>{\mainline{1.a4}}
        \only<2>{\hidemoves{1.a4}}
        \chessboard
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This code shall work for an alone pawn, but it doesn't moves:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{chessboard, skak}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \newgame\setchessboard{markstyle=border,color=blue}
        \only<1>{\mainline{1.a4}}
        \only<2>{\hidemoves{1.a4}}
        \chessboard[setpieces = {Pa2}] % Pawn
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[Documentation for the lib](ftp://tug.ctan.org/pub/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/chessboard/chessboard.pdf)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5764) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 12):

I am not sure if something like this is what you are trying to achieve:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{chessboard, skak}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \newgame\setchessboard{markstyle=border,color=blue}
        \only<1>{\chessboard[setpieces = {Pa2}]}
        \only<2>{\chessboard[setpieces = {Pa4}]}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No, I want chess lib to make moves for me. :)

Answer (score 6):

You can set a startposition with the `\fenboard` command. With `xskak` it is easier, there you can fill the board with pieces. Using only a white piece doesn't make much sense, `\mainline` will not like it if black can't move. But you could e.g. use the key `hideblack` to hide the black piece:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{chessboard, xskak}
\begin{document}
\setchessboard{markstyle=border,color=blue}
    \begin{frame}
        \newchessgame[setpieces={Pa2,ph7}]
        \only<1>{Startposition}
        \only<2>{\mainline{1.a4}}
        \only<3>{\hidemoves{1.a4 h5}\mainline{2.a5}}
        \only<4>{\hidemoves{1.a4 h5 2.a5 h4}\mainline{3.a6}}
        \only<5>{\hidemoves{1.a4 h5 2.a5 h4 3.a6 h3}\mainline{4.a7}}
        \only<6>{\hidemoves{1.a4 h5 2.a5 h4 3.a6 h3 4.a7 h2}\mainline{5.a8=Q}}

        \chessboard[hideblack]
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: And how to add `\setchessboard` command?
It looks better...

Comment: What do you mean? There is a `\setchessboard` command in my code.

Comment: Yes. But your variant doesn't look same.

Comment: I don't see any difference between the boards in your example and in mine (apart from the fact there are less pieces on my board). I also don't see any reason why they should be a difference.

Comment: In your variant a string with information is located above the chessboard.

Comment: Well yes, I thought it would look better than to the left like in your code. If you don't like remove the empty line before `\chessboard`. Or use only `\hidemoves` and no `\mainline`.

Comment: Thanks. And do you know how to enable colours for all these chess?

Comment: Yes, I know how to do it. But chessboard has a quite large documentation with a lot of examples so please try first to find a solution yourself.

Comment: If I hadn't tried before, I wouldn't ask!